# How to create a fake / "virtual" file?

Tags: php, stream, filestream

I am trying to create a "virtual" file without using either memory or a temporary file. The "virtual" file needs to pass a check made with `file_exists()` while not throwing any error or warning when used with `require` or `include`.

> Allows you to implement your own protocol handlers and streams for use with [all the other filesystem functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) (such as `fopen()`, `fread()` etc.).

…where `file_exists()` is one of them. [The docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) states:

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) to determine which wrappers support [`stat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) family of functionality.

My attempt there was to build a custom, virtual file wrapper

```
class VirtualFileWrapper
{
    public $context;

    public function stream_open( $path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path )
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function stream_stat()
    {
        var_dump( __METHOD__ );
        $data = [
            'dev'     => 0,
            'ino'     => getmyinode(),
            'mode'    => 'r',
            'nlink'   => 0,
            'uid'     => getmyuid(),
            'gid'     => getmygid(),
            'rdev'    => 0,
            'size'    => 0,
            'atime'   => time(),
            'mtime'   => getlastmod(),
            'ctime'   => FALSE,
            'blksize' => 0,
            'blocks'  => 0,
        ];
        return array_merge( array_values( $data ), $data );
    }
}

stream_wrapper_register( 'virtual', 'VirtualFileWrapper' );

$file = fopen( "virtual://foo", 'r+' );

// Executes VirtualFileWrapper::stream_stat()
fstat( $file );

// Executes no VirtualFileWrapper method
file_exists( $file );
```

While the `fstat()` function executes the method, `file_exists()` does not execute any stream class method.

How could I get a virtual stream wrapper to work (with `file_exists()`)?

---

I am fully aware that `tempnam( __DIR__, '' )` will pass both:

- `var_dump( tempnam( __DIR__, '' ) );` Returns `true`
- `require tempnam( __DIR__, '' );` No error

but I do not want to use a temporary file as there might be a better way (performance wise).

Comment: You can't. file_exists() expects a string as its argument. You can pass in an object that implements the magic __toString() method, but then file_exists will `stat()` that string and fail, because the file doesn't really exist.

Comment: @MarcB Actually [**Drupal** has that working](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/24233/55237). I just could not really figure out how as the `vfsStream` stuff is just that messed up in source.

Comment: Why are you trying to accomplish with this? I think that creating a fake file is a very strange practice.

Comment: @kaiser the answer you linked to on Drupal.SE *is* passing a string. In your example you are passing a *resource* - the output of `fopen()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you just need to implement a public `url_stat()` method on  `VirtualFileWrapper` for it to pass the `file_exists()` check.

To silence warnings and errors from `include` and `require`, you must implement `stream_read()` and `stream_eof()` methods:

```
class VirtualFileWrapper
{
    public $context;

    public function stream_open( $path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path )
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function stream_stat()
    {
        var_dump( __METHOD__ );
        return [];
    }

    public function url_stat()
    {
        return array (
          0 => 0,
          1 => 0,
          2 => 0,
          3 => 0,
          4 => 0,
          5 => 0,
          6 => 0,
          7 => 0,
          8 => 0,
          9 => 0,
          10 => 0,
          11 => 0,
          12 => 0,
          'dev' => 0,
          'ino' => 0,
          'mode' => 0,
          'nlink' => 0,
          'uid' => 0,
          'gid' => 0,
          'rdev' => 0,
          'size' => 0,
          'atime' => 0,
          'mtime' => 0,
          'ctime' => 0,
          'blksize' => 0,
          'blocks' => 0
        );
    }

    public function stream_read(){
        return '';
    }

    public function stream_eof(){
        return '';
    }

}

stream_wrapper_register( 'virtual', 'VirtualFileWrapper' );

$file = fopen( "virtual://foo", 'r+' );

// Executes VirtualFileWrapper::stream_stat()
fstat( $file );

// Executes no VirtualFileWrapper method
file_exists("virtual://foo");

//Still no errors :-)!
require "virtual://foo";
include "virtual://foo";
```

Take care to pass `file_exists()` a string, rather than the resource you created with `fopen()`.

Comment: I wish I could provide more details - I have no idea why this works, Ill come back and edit if I figure it out.

Comment: After trying this for hours, I am really glad you jumped in: My example was close to no different to yours, aside from the fact, that I returned `stat()` inside `url_stat()`. Looks like I need to learn to read :P The [`return` value](http://php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.url-stat.php) clearly states that. Thanks a ton! Btw, another strange thing is that both `require` as `include` get called _twice_ in my local test.